# Explanation of an example of NG -Table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Someone can explain this example

[Plunker NG-Table](http://plnkr.co/edit/CBcbkc?p=info)

In the HTML, there is -->

```
<tbody ng-repeat="group in $groups">
```

But in the js there is no why ?

> $groups

Comment: The groups are defined specifying the `groupBy` ngTableParameter see https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/wiki/Configuring-your-table-with-ngTableParams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ngTable module](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table) defines the $scope.$groups when the `groupBy` ngTableParameter is specified ([you can see it in the github source code here](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/blob/master/src/scripts/03-params.js) ).

```
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1,            // show first page
    count: 10          // count per page
}, {
    groupBy: 'role',   // << ----- grouping parameter
    total: data.length,
    getData: function($defer, params) {
        var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                $filter('orderBy')(data, $scope.tableParams.orderBy()) :
                data;

        $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
    }
});
```

This is the $groups created on the $scope by ngTable, for the data in the plunker example.

```
$scope.$groups = [
            {
                value: 'Administrator',
                data: [
                    {name: "Moroni", age: 50, role: 'Administrator'},
                    {name: "Tiancum", age: 43, role: 'Administrator'},
                    {name: "Jacob", age: 27, role: 'Administrator'}
                ]
            },
            {
                value: 'Moderator',
                data: [
                    {name: "Nephi", age: 29, role: 'Moderator'},
                    {name: "Nephi", age: 29, role: 'Moderator'},
                    {name: "Tiancum", age: 43, role: 'Moderator'},
                    {name: "Enos", age: 34, role: 'Moderator'}
                ]
            },
            {
                value: 'User',
                data: [
                    {name: "Enos", age: 34, role: 'User'},
                    {name: "Tiancum", age: 43, role: 'User'},
                    {name: "Jacob", age: 27, role: 'User'},
                    {name: "Enos", age: 34, role: 'User'},
                    {name: "Jacob", age: 27, role: 'User'},
                    {name: "Nephi", age: 29, role: 'User'},
                    {name: "Tiancum", age: 43, role: 'User'},
                    {name: "Jacob", age: 27, role: 'User'},
                    {name: "Nephi", age: 29, role: 'User'},
                    {name: "Enos", age: 34, role: 'User'}
                ]
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Why when i do a console.log($scope); i don't see the $groups ..?

Comment: A guess, by looking at the source code, is that because the $groups is set in a promise callback, the promise might not be resolved yet when you execute the console.log($scope) call.